# Audio Interface is not showing up in System Preferences Output Input

Tags: mac

Running Catalina OS. Unfortunately when plugging in my Focusrite Saffire 6 interface it is not recognized in System Preferences > Sound > Output Input. Very frustrating. I am using the correct high speed USB cable and the interface is showing up in my USB tree (About this mac > System Report > Hardware > USB) but only 'Internal Speakers' shows up in System Preference Output and Input. I can't find anything online about how to get the mac to recognize the interface. Only an article about deleting temp files which I did to no success. Also downloaded drivers for the USB 1.1 driver even though I am pretty sure I am running 2.0.

Comment: I have found that unplugging the audio devices and putting the computer to sleep will often fix this type of issue.   In more extreme cases I have had to restart the computer as well.  Have you already tried these tow methods?

Comment: Never had a Focusrite, but my Line6 needs to be plugged in at boot,  otherwise will not be recognised.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I experienced this previously on another machine. It was annoying. I did try unpulgging and rebooting but I believe this model is being phased out which may be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Focusrite doesn't support Saffire 6 any longer with MAC Catalina 10.15.x. They stopped after the 10.15 update. It's useless to me now.

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded to Mojave and Focusrite provides a driver for USB 1.1 however I downloaded the driver and ran it but still nothing.